# Polymer-redux object observing

Tags: javascript, redux, polymer, polymer-2.x

So I am using redux with polymer 2.0 and its working very well. Then I suddenly came across a problem and I cannot for the life of me find out what I should be doing.

```
  settings:{
              type:Object,
              statePath: 'setting.documentSettings',
              observer:'_extendedInfo'
          }
```

---

```
  const settingsReducer = (state={"documentSettings":{},"searchSettings":{},"discussionSettings":{},"entrySettings":{}}, action) => {
```

And then in my action.

```
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
                                documentSettings: setting
                             });
```

Also I have multiple reducers that are combined thats why its setting.documentSettings in my property

So I change the object documentSettings, and the property settings does change, which is great. The observer is never hit though and I cannot find an example anywhere of this.

Comment: It looks like you are subscribing to something that is in your store in the "`settings`" object, under the "`documentSettings`" key, but in your redux action you are overwriting "directly" to a key called "`documentSettings`" in the top level of your store, not under the "`settings`" object.

Comment: That is because I have multiple reducers. @mishu

Answer (score 1):

I think [mishu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521598/mishu)'s comment explains why the observer isn't firing.

Leaving aside Redux for a moment, the following Polymer properties code creates an observer on the path `settings`:

```
settings: {
  type:Object,
  observer:'_extendedInfo'
}
```

Observing the path `settings` will give you changes to the top-level property `settings`, but not its sub-properties, because of the way Polymer implements observers.

If I understand your code correctly (not necessarily the case), I think you actually need a complex observer on `settings.*`, because you need to observe any change to any of the subpaths too: `settings.documentSettings`, `settings.searchSettings`, etc etc.

To create a complex observer like that, it would be something like

```
static get observers() {
  return [
    // Observer method name, followed by a list of dependencies, in parenthesis
    '_extendedInfo(settings.*)'
  ];
}
```

Note that for observing a wildcard path like `settings.*`, you would declare the observer in the `observers` array (see the [Polymer 2.0 docs on complex observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers)) rather than in the declaration of the property itself.

See also the [Polymer 2.0 docs on what constitutes an observable change to Polymer data system](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes).

Hope that helps and that I haven't wildly misunderstood what you're doing... good luck

Comment: Yes this has fixed half the problem. It hits the observer but the way I am returning my value from redux is not right and its not receiving a value.